# Is there a way to ask InstallShield to set "modified" timestamp for installed files to current date/time?

Tags: installshield

I have an application that precomputes and caches some data after installation. The logic to check if we need to rebuild this cache was pretty and simple: if the cache "modified" timestamp is older than the source file, then we need to update it. This way when we change something in this file or simply install a new version of application, timestamp of relevant source file is going to be updated, become bigger than timestamp of cached file and cache will be rebuilt once. Then "cached" file timestamp gets bigger than "source" and no further rebuilds happen.

Well, it worked, except it turns out now that InstallShield does not set "modified" timestamp for files, just copies timestamps of original files. Is there a way to override this behavior and force IS to set "modified" timestamps to date/time of the moment of installation?

Comment: Why not set this property on the file(s) before building your installer? Shouldn't be too hard to accomplish with Powershell or Python or some other fav scripting language.

Comment: This property must be set after installation, but indeed, adding an additional installation step that touches recently installed files was our main idea for workaround. But I heard that InstallShield had some kind of flag that allowed to configure InstallShield to do this itself. After all changing "modified" timestamp to specific value is not something that happens automatically, it's an additional step that IS does and I even saw reported bugs that it didn't worked in some cases (on netwofk file system). Is it possible to skip this step?